# Accessing the irb in a modular Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, irb

I am building an application which subclasses Sinatra like so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  ...

  run!
end
```

How can I access irb? Options are not parsed when executing sinatra this way, how do I programmatically open an irb shell?

Comment: `require 'irb'`  and then in the code `IRB.start`

Comment: you could also use ```pry``` if you want to have some debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little confused whether you want to open an IRB session from within your app (?) or use IRB to debug your Sinatra project?

For debugging Rack-based apps (such as Sinatra), I like using the [**racksh gem**](http://rubygems.org/gems/racksh), which "*is like script/console in Rails*" for Rack applications. Its main advantage over IRB is that racksh loads the entire application environment into the shell, making debugging a breeze.

From racksh's [**Github page**](https://github.com/sickill/racksh): "It's purpose is to allow developer to introspect his application and/or make some initial setup. You can for example run DataMapper.auto_migrate! or make a request to /users/666 and check response details. It's mainly aimed at apps that don't have console-like component (ie. apps built with Sinatra) but all frameworks can benefit from interactive Rack stack and request introspection."

However, racksh requires your app to have a `config.ru` file, so you would have to re-write your app:

```rb
# in config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'app.rb'


# in app.rb
class App < Sinatra::Base
  ...

  run!
end
```

Then in your app folder (where config.ru resides):

```
$ gem install racksh # or add gem 'racksh' to your Gemfile and run bundle
$ racksh
```

Comment: There is also the [**`tux` gem**](https://github.com/cldwalker/tux): an interactive Sinatra shell. "Use it to interact with your helpers, view rendering and your app’s response objects. Tux also gives you commands to view your app’s routes and settings."

Answer (score 10):

Just type as below (at the shell prompt):

```
irb -r ./my_app.rb
```

Comment: And `RACK_ENV=preprod irb -r ./my_app.rb` if you need to launch an interactive Sinatra for a particular environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple search interface for Microsoft's Bing using [Sinatra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_%28software%29) and `binger` gem.
If you follow the instructions from there you will understand better.

First at all, create a Gemfile and add:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'binger'
```

Then run the `bundle` command that will generated `Gemfile.lock`.
Then create a `config.ru` file, and add by example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require './app.rb'

run MyApp
```

Your `app.rb` could look like this:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do

      @title = "Index" 

      erb:index

  end
end
```

You must have a folder named `views`. Create `index.erb` and add:

```
< % = @title % >
```

Finally, run `rackup`.

Source: https://github.com/thinkphp/sinatra-bing

Demo: http://sinatra-bing.herokuapp.com/