# Ruby How do I parse through this response to store the users work experience in a database

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth, linkedin-api

I am using OmniAuth LinkedIn to authenticate and store the users information. This is the output displayed when i YAML::dump(response.env['omniauth.auth'].extra.raw_info)

My question: How to I parse through this response to store the users work experience (the several companies listed) and the users education?

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
educations: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  _total: 1
  values:
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    degree: ! '"BS"'
    endDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      year: 2014
    fieldOfStudy: Information Technology
    id: 154175914
    schoolName: Florida State University
    startDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      year: 2012
emailAddress: mci12@my.fsu.edu
firstName: Michael
headline: Co founder/CTO at Prept.co
id: 9rFcoUgX7u
industry: Information Technology and Services
lastName: Iglesias
location: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  country: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    code: us
  name: Miami/Fort Lauderdale Area
pictureUrl: http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_eyd5KS_5QNRWff1-HxoVKfQQX-yWSdi-EgjVKaLVRAeMtSqtXsJWOmlqospnaaGOWxIUxWULYrkb
positions: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  _total: 4
  values:
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    company: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      industry: Information Technology and Services
      name: InterviewChamp.co
    id: 409892806
    isCurrent: true
    startDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      month: 4
      year: 2013
    summary: Online marketplace where job seekers can connect with industry professionals
  in their desired fields for online video conferencing practice interviews. Job
  seekers are able to practice case, behavioral, and technical interviews to help
  them prepare and excel at real interviews.
    title: Founder/CTO
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    company: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      industry: Information Technology and Services
      name: Open Momento Web Development
    id: 385398346
    isCurrent: true
    startDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      month: 5
      year: 2012
    title: Software Engineer
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
     company: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      industry: Information Technology and Services
      name: LetUsDorm.com
    id: 385404241
    isCurrent: true
    startDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      month: 1
      year: 2012
    title: Founder/CEO
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    company: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      id: 2780
       industry: Information Technology and Services
      name: Amadeus
      size: 10,001+ employees
      type: Public Company
    endDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      month: 5
      year: 2012
    id: 385401346
    isCurrent: false
    startDate: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
      month: 5
      year: 2011
    title: IT Intern
publicProfileUrl: http://www.linkedin.com/in/iglesiasm
```

This is what I have in my app.rb file which is based on sinatra...

```
%w(get post).each do |method|
    send(method, "/auth/:provider/callback") do

        response =  (request.env['omniauth.auth']).extra.raw_info
        "<pre>" + YAML::dump(response) + "</pre>" + "<br /><br />" 
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby and this is driving me crazy. I am able to access the email address, id, and all other first tier attributes, but I simply can't figure out how to iterate through those nested entities to extract all of the information I want to store like work experience, etc...

Comment: Try a YAML::parse (...) on the yaml data and then do an inspect.You may want to try it in irb to poke around.

Comment: check the code block above and I included what I have within my method

Comment: @PaulRubel - how would I do what you have recommended I try? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like the following:

```
res = YAML::parse(response)
```

you can then do something like so:

```
puts res.inspect # show the nested bits via  stdout
                 # or through some other logging
```

Not having ominauth I can't test for sure but it looks like you can access elements like so.

```
res["lastname"] # -> Iglesias
res["educations]["id"] # -> 154175914
res["location"]["country"]...
```

You may want to try some solution to get a debugger around sinatra, perhaps [racksh](https://github.com/sickill/racksh). [Accessing the irb in a modular Sinatra application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890641/accessing-the-irb-in-a-modular-sinatra-application)